# LDA - Assigning keywords to topics

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, gensim, lda, unsupervised-learning

I have unstructured data of about 150k documents. I am trying to group these documents using unsupervised learning algorithm. Currently I am using LDA (Latent Dirichlet allocation) in gensim Python. For LDAModel I have passed num_topics=20. Hence my whole 150k data is falling into 20 topics.

Now that I have these groups, I have 2 questions:

1. How should I assign new documents to these topics?

The approach I am taking is:
Calculate the sum of the word scores of the document per topic and assign the document to the topic with the highest score. However this is not giving me good results.

Is there any better way to get this?

2. How do I assign the main keywords that denote the topic?

Comment: If your topics are predefined, this is a classification and not a clustering problem.

Comment: I have modified the question, predefined meaning I have given 20 as the parameter for num_topics.

Answer (score 0):

**How should I assign new documents to these topics?**

Once you have a trained model you can query the `model` for your document with:

```
doc_bow = model.id2word.doc2bow(doc.split()) # convert to bag of words format first
doc_topics, word_topics, phi_values = model.get_document_topics(bow, per_word_topics=True)
```

re. 
This code is going to provide you with per-doc and per-word information about the level of belonging to a particular topic. This means the per-word calculations are done for you automatically.

**How do I assign the main keywords that denote the topic?**

it is difficult to understand what you mean. The keywords denoting a topic along with their weights are the actual LDA model that you got from the training using a corpus.

---

I suppose you may be interested in reviewing [the following notebook](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_methods.ipynb) [*] for more information how to query model for specific information regarding a  document (per-word topic information, etc.).

[*] from which I took the excerpt of the code above